# Fat models and skinny controllers sounds like creating God models

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, architecture, god-object

I've been reading a lot of blogs which advocate the *fat models and skinny controllers* approach, esp. the Rails camp. As a result the routers is basically just figuring out what method to call on what controller and all the controller method does is call the corresponding method on the model and then bring up the view. So I've two concerns here which I don't understand:

1. The controller and router are really not doing much different tasks other than just calling a method on the God-like model based on the route.
2. Models are doing too much. Sending emails, creating relationships, deleting and modifying other models, queuing tasks, etc. Basically now you have God-like objects that are supposed to do everything that may or may not concern with modeling and dealing with data.

Where do you draw the line? Isn't this just falling into the God pattern?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

> <sub>It might not be the best idea to look at Rails as a staple of MVC design pattern. Said framework was made with some inherent shortcomings (I kinda elaborated on it in a [different post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11984678/727208)) and the community only just now has begun addressing the fallout. You could look at DataMapper2 [development](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MU4RvuvpT8w) as the first major step.</sub>

#### Some theory

People giving that advice seem to be afflicted by a quite common misconception. So let me begin by clearing it up: **Model, in modern MVC design pattern, is NOT a class or object.** Model is a layer.

The core idea behind MVC pattern is [*Separation of Concerns*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and the first step in it is the division between presentation layer and model layers. Just like the presentation layer breaks down into controllers (instances, responsible for dealing with user input), views (instances, responsible for UI logic) and templates/layouts, so does the model layer.

The major parts that the model layer consists of are:

- [Domain Objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject)

  Also known as domain entities, business objects, or model objects (I dislike that latter name because it just adds to the confusion). These structures are what people usually mistakenly call "models". They are responsible for containing business rules (all the math and validation for specific unit of domain logic).
- Storage Abstractions:

  Usually implemented using [data mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) pattern (do not confuse with [ORMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), which have abused this name). These instances usually are tasked with information storage-from and retrieval-into the domain objects. Each domain object can have several mappers, just like there are several forms of storage (DB, cache, session, cookies, /dev/null).
- Services:

  Structures responsible for application logic (that is, interaction between domain objects and interaction between domain objects and storage abstractions). They should act like the "interface" through which the presentation layer interacts with the model layer. This is usually what in Rails-like code ends up in the controllers.

There are also several structures that might be in the spaces between these groups: [DAOs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html), [units of work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) and [repositories](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html).

> <sub>Oh ... and when we talk (in context of web) about a *user* that interacts with MVC application, it is not a human being. The "user" is actually your web browser.</sub>

#### So what about deities?

Instead of having some scary and monolithic model to work with, controllers should interact with services. You pass data from user input to a specific service (for example `MailService` or `RecognitionService`). This way the controller changes the state of model layer, but it is done by using a clear API and without messing with internal structures (which would cause a leaky abstraction).

Such changes can either cause some immediate reaction, or only affect the data that the view instance requests from model layer, or both.

Each service can interact with any number (though, it's usually only a handful) of domain object and storage abstractions. For example, the `RecogitionService` could not care less about storage abstractions for the articles.

#### Closing notes

This way you get an application that can be unit-tested at any level, has low coupling (if correctly implemented) and has clearly understandable architecture.

Though, keep in mind: MVC is not meant for small applications. If you are writing a guestbook page using MVC pattern, you are doing it wrong. This pattern is meant for enforcing *law and order* on large scale applications.

> <sub>For people who are using PHP as primary language, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864000/727208) might be relevant. It's a bit longer description of the model layer with a few snippets of code.</sub>

Comment: Very useful and complete answer! Do you know any book that explain a bit more the MVC architectural pattern? Expecially on the models part that everyone mistakenly thinks "The model represents the data, and does nothing else." and that sounds more like the idea of  domain object, not the 'Model' -> http://tomdalling.com/blog/software-design/model-view-controller-explained/

Comment: @thermz, *afaik*, there really are no books that deal exclusively with MVC pattern. I usually just tell people to read [**PoEAA**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0321127420), and then go digging. Maybe this [**list of links**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16356866/727208) could be useful. I find that, when people have a solid grasp on OOP principles and concepts, the pattern becomes quite easy to understand.

Comment: @tereško beautiful answer. Does Hibernate achieve this? I'm not convinced by the answers here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308096/which-pattern-does-hibernate-follow

Comment: @Ankan-Zerob as you might notice, I am not a java developer, but from what I know about Hibernate, it provides a complete toolset for for persistence layer. It will give you part of what's described there, but **not** a complete model layer.

Comment: @tereško Can you tell me how this helps?  I understand the separation of concerns, but sooner or later one has to change the logic that hits the database.  This will in turn require, possibly, a new method, somewhere, and that new method has to be called from somewhere else.  So changes do seem to cascade up the chain from m to v to c.  How does this change something in the model layer, the service or whatever layer, from becoming huge?  Thanks.  I've looked everywhere and I cannot find an answer to any of the MVC questions other than "well that's just how you do it,"whether this MVC or other.

Comment: @tereško It's all just very confusing because some layer of abstraction has to change sooner or later.

Comment: @johnny  Why would changes in DB logic (which is handled by [data mappers](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html)) propagate beyond service layer? Hell, the changes shouldn't even get that far, if your are passing in the domain object in generic mapper's method calls: `$userMapper->save($user)`. Why would you need to change this interface, if you decide to store users in two tables instead of one?

Comment: @tereško I think it is getting clearer.  Is there any framework that "does it right"?  Particularly PHP.  It doesn't have to be that, Java is good too.  Anything?

Comment: @johnny not as far as I know. Most of php's so-called "mvc frameworks" are variations of Rails. And, as part of the course, most of them come with some [active record](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) based ORM solutions (those things are notoriously fragile to DB changes). You **can** implement something like this with SF2.x or ZF2.x, but the point of a framework is not to implement/enforce a specific architecture but to provide tools. Also, when it comes to MVC, it is implemented by **application code** and not the framework.

Comment: Short answer: I am not aware of any framework which significantly favors above described approach.

Comment: The introduction uses the word "inherit" when what is meant is "inherent". I don't have enough rep to fix it and the change isn't substantial enough as a proposed edit, so can someone else correct this please?

Answer (score 5):

If the "model" classes are implemented poorly yes, your concern is relevant.
A model class shouldnt be doing Email (infrastructure tasks).

The real question is what does model in MVC imply.
It isnt restricted to POCO classes with a few methods.
Model in MVC means Data and Business logic.  Treat it as a superset of classic core POCO models.

**View ==== Controller ==== Model     ---> Business Process layer --> Core models**

Throw in Infrastructure assemblies and Data Access layers and use injection to hand that into the  BPL then your a process is using MVC as intended.

BPL may invoke UoW / Respository patterns,   and  execute business rules and call Infrastructure features by way of injected Objects or interface patters.

So the recommendation to keep a controller skinny doesnt mean the "person" class in a classic Core model should have 50 methods, and call Email directly. You are right to think this is wrong.

The Controller May still be required to instantiate and inject Infrastructure classes into the BPL or core layer if called directly.  There should be a business layer or at least classes orchestrating calls across Classic Object model classes.
Well thats my "view" anyway ;-)

For generic take on MVC the wiki description http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

A Little Blog that talks about the "M" in MVC. http://www.thedeveloperday.com/skinny-controllers/

Comment: If you disagree at least be courteous enough to justify your view

Answer (score -1):

I think you can make a distinction between a single fat model (possibly named App or Application), and several fat models broken down into logical groups (Business, Customer, Order, Message).  The latter is how I structure my apps, and each model roughly corresponds to a database table in a relational database or collection in a document database.  These models handle all aspects of creating, updating, and manipulating the data that makes up the model, whether it is talking to the database or calling an API.  The controller is very thinm responsible for little mor that calling the appropriate model and selecting a template.