# In proper MVC, does everything have to be a model, view, or controller?

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4, yii

Something I have been wondering but somewhat too embarrassed to ask until now: In "proper" MVC (strictly adhering to the pattern), does everything have to be a model, view, or controller? If not, can you provide an example of when breaking the pattern is advisable or necessary? Finally, what is the role of class (or static) methods in MVC?

Concrete example: I have models `OneModel` and `TwoModel`. There is no natural reason to think of them as being inherited from some superclass. Both have completely different properties but they do share an `emailAddress` field and I want to `validateEmailAddress()` for each model sometimes. I don't want to copy over validation code in each model so I make a `ValidationHelper` class with class method `validateEmailAddress(String emailAddress)` that I will now call in each of `OneModel` and `TwoModel`.

Have I now broken the pattern? How can I fix it?

Comment: One way to do this would be to define a class `EmailAddress` that holds the address and the validation logic. Then if you want give it its own View that you can then use to display it.

Comment: Would `EmailAddress` be a model (ie `OneModel` and `TwoModel` *have* an `EmailAddress` in the DB) or would it just be plain old class?

Comment: From the perspective of your UI code it would act as a model. It would still be just a plain old class.

Comment: Your example seems nothing to do with MVC. The problem is code duplication which you can solve with attaching behavior in yii or using traits in php 5.4+. Also yii actually has email validator built in which leaves you with only a field with same name - i would not make a whole behavior for just a field. KISS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see Model, View and Controller as the layers of the application and not just components of the presentation layer, then your email validation class would be part of the Model layer because it contains business logic. I don't see where you break the pattern, not every model class has to be a data object.

The problem with "strictly adhering to the pattern" is that the pattern has evolved over time. The original pattern was intended for GUIs of single user applications. Later it was adapted for the web but with different interpretations, especially regarding responsibilities between model and controller and also between client and server. So prepare to get different answers without a single "true" one.

Comment: I hate to break it to you, but MVC does not means "my very code". While the application of SoC principle might vary, then core responsibilities stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

The MVC design pattern is comprised of two major parts:

- presentation layer
- model layer

Presentation layer provides a way for users to interact with model layer while model layer contains all of the business logic and associated task.

Model is not a class or object. Instead it contains several groups of structures, each with different aspect of domain business logic as its responsibility. You can read a longer explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14045514/727208).

The presentation layer is mostly divided based on what how it interacts with model layer. You could say that controllers "write" to the model layer (through services) and views "read" from it.

The simplest part in whole MVC design patter (and other MVC-inspired patterns) should be the controller. They take user input and based on that alter model layer's state. They can alter views too, but, when MVC is applied to web, it more of an exception then a rule.

As for views - I am still trying to figure them out. What I currently got can be read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16596704/727208).

> <sub>**Note:** there is a severe lack of material regarding implementation of views, when applied to Web. Since the platform is completely different, when compared to desktop applications, it is impossible to transplant the same guidelines direct. And I have not found any framework-unrelated material on the subject, that focused on creating views for Web.</sub>

Comment: I have a tendency to think about views in a slightly sloppy way: A view is anything that is responsible for displaying things. So in a way when you use templates your templates are the view and when you use classes from a framework that produce interface elements those are also part of the view.

The important distinction is the one between presentation layer and model layer anyway.

Comment: @confusopoly, templates are not views

Comment: Like I said, I think about this in a sloppy way.

Answer (score 1):

You must understand that MVC is an **architectural pattern**. As so, it is a higher level pattern, that describes how your components are organized and interact with each other. To achieve this organization, you will need a set of specialized components that will do de "dirty work" for you. In this set, probably you will have some components that does not fit in the definition of any letter M-V-C, some components have just helping functions, others are on the interface between the layers, working on their integration.

So, the answer is **no**, not everthing is a Model, a View or a Controller.