# Yii2 SRP possibly violated in model

Tags: php, oop, yii2

I am writing application in Yii2 framework. It has `User` model used by Controllers. This model has these methods:

- classic methods for database entity management
- methods for management files of user
- authentification and authorisation methods

I think, this class violate Sigle Responsibility Principle (SRP), becouse it has at least 3 reasons to change. Its functionality could also split into separate classes (models/components/something else).
So I thought to redesign this and apply something, what can fix this. But I don't know how can I do this by using Yii2 and not to violate MVC principle. The best solution could be use som Yii2 features. Should I split this one model to more components or even models? Should I redesign my database and normalize my user table? What could be the best possible solution?

Comment: [The Model in MVC is a layer, not a class or object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044681/fat-models-and-skinny-controllers-sounds-like-creating-god-models/14045514#14045514)

Comment: Ok, I mean that I have class User which exted classs ActiveRecord which extends BaseActiveRecord which extends Model... Therefore I am talking about model(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application has a `yii\web\User` class. To quote the guide, *User is the class for the "user" application component that manages the user authentication status.* It has `identity` attribute that is your ActiveRecord descendant (your `app\models\User` class).

So `app\models\User` implements `IdentityInterface`, but that is just a set of getter methods to map `yii\web\User`'s attributes like access token to relevant attributes of your model.

Lastly, `app\models\User` has nothing to do with managing user files. If you're talking about user roles, which *can* be stored as files, `yii\rbac\PhpManager` is used for that purpose.

To summarize:

- **database entry management** is implemented in `app\models\User`
- **authentication** (finding out who is who) is implemented in `yii\web\User`
- **authorization** (finding out who can do what) is implemented in `yii\rbac\PhpManager` or another manager or access control lists
- user files are managed elsewhere