# list out what design patterns used in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

Can you **list** out all **design patterns used in Hibernate** frame work?

I knew some some of design patterns like DAO, ORM, etc.

If possible some examples.

Comment: there is already some like this in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308096/which-pattern-does-hibernate-follow)

Comment: ORM means Object Relational Mapping, it is not a design pattern, more a type of framework (like hibernate, toplink, mybatis, ...). Your question is too broad to be addressed in one post, you should check the link given by @calazans and learn about those patterns one after another.

Answer (score 3):

Design patterns used in Hibernate :

- Domain Model Pattern – An object model of the domain that incorporates both behavior and data.
- Proxy Pattern for lazy loading.
- Factory pattern in SessionFactory

Answer (score 3):

Design patterns used in Hibernate

**Domain Model Pattern** – An object model of the domain that incorporates both behavior and data.

**Proxy Pattern** for lazy loading.

**Unit of Work** (as part of Session object)

**Factory Pattern** in Session Factory

**Query Object** for Criterion API

**Data Mapper** – A layer of Mappers that moves data between objects and a database while keeping them independent of each other and the mapper itself.

**Active Record Pattern**

**DAO**

**Object-Relational Mapping(ORM)**

etc